# LWC for URL conversion

Tags: lightning-web-components, urlhacking

We have been encountering a lot of switches to classical as lightning users have to share links to classic only users. To avoid those switches I wanted to give a Global action which can convert lightning url to equivalent classic url. Looking for idea on best way to go about implementing this.

Comment: Do you want the LWC to sit on the record page, and basically click a button to copy the classic version of the link?

Comment: Not on a record page, instead at global action.